# How to use 'this' in jQuery plugin callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

At the moment I am creating a jQuery plugin.

I am facing a problem when using a callback.

### Plugin code

```
$.fn.bondye = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        callback: function () {}
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('test');
        settings.callback();
    });
};
```

### How I want to execute the code

```
$(".myDiv").bondye({
    callback: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("test");
    }
});
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/HEJtm/1/

But I aint able to do anything with the div within the callback.

I used http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/ to learn developing jQuery plugins, but I cannot find anything about callbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the context for your callback. You can use `call`:

```
settings.callback.call(this);
```

Comment: @Bondye: actually he was 6 seconds faster than me :-) Could you please move a check mark to this answer?

Comment: @zerkms, OK If you agree :) You won't miss the reputation with 81k :P

Answer (score 5):

Invoke it as

```
settings.callback.call(this);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

Pass `this` back when you invoke `callback()`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.bondye = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            callback: function () {}
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('test');

            // Pass "this" back here:
            settings.callback(this);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(".myDiv").bondye({
    callback: function (obj) {
        $(obj).removeClass("test");
    }
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GwNym/).

**Option 2:** (preferred)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.bondye = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            callback: function () {}
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('test');
            settings.callback.call(this);
            settings.callback();
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(".myDiv").bondye({
    callback: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("test");
    }
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kc7Tk/).